# ipython using python2 although python3 is defined in the PATH

Tags: python, ipython

As shown in the following snippets - the paths point for `python` and `ipython` seem to all point to `3.x`- however the result is launching `2.x`. I am on `macos High Sierra` Any thoughts?

- Which `python` are we using (3.X):

  which python
  /usr/local/bin/python

  $python --version
  Python 3.6.4
- Which `python` is `ipython` pointing to (3.X ?)

```
    cat  $(which ipython)
    #!/usr/local/bin/python

    import re
    import sys

    from IPython import start_ipython

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

- So let's run `ipython` - and then which `python` version is launched (***2***.X ??):

  $ipython
  Python 2.7.15 (default, Jun 26 2018, 09:40:54)
  Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

  IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

**Update** There was a comment about `ipython3`: I had looked into that as well before posting.  After running

```
pip3 install ipython
```

the results were `Requirement already satisfied` for all dependencies. Afterwards however `ipython3` still does not appear in the `$PATH`.

Comment: try `ipython3`!

Comment: there is no `ipython3` in the `$PATH` -  I had checked that earlier.

Comment: you can install both `ipython3` and `ipython` using apt ( if you're using a debian base distro ), the only time that ipython uses python3 is when u are running it inside a virtualenv that has been created using python3, try `sudo apt install ipython3 && pip3 install ipython`

Comment: btw I am on `macos`: updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the following is not - by far - an optimal solution it is a workaround for now:

```
alias ipython3='python3 -m IPython'
```

Multiple questions from the OP still remain as to why the various `PATH` elements are not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change the PATH or use a virtual environment.

If you do not want to use conda you can use virtualenv.

You can install this with `$ pip install virtualenv`. Make sure you install it for the right Python version.

After that you can create a virtual environment by creating a folder and then executing `python3 -m venv env`

You activate the environment in your shell / console with the `source env/bin/activate` command.

If the command is successful your shell will show the environment in brackets.

Every virtual environment will have it's own set of packages but packages that you installed globally will be available when you built the environment.

This will work under Linux and Windows. Keep in mind that Windows does not have a shell.

Here is a full [primer](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

Comment: There are reasons why I am not using `virtualenv`. If you can identify why the `PATH` is not working properly (for native `python3`/`ipython3`) that would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? If windows then you have to explicitly set a hook in the installer if you want to change the path on installation. It is possible that other programs/tools still need python2. If you can make absolutely sure that this is not the case then you can simply change the PATH. However the virtual environments are exactly made for your problem/scenario. Is there are reason why you can't use them?

Comment: I don't want to go into the  reasons why I am not using a `virtualenv` (/`conda` , etc).  They have all been looked at (and tried) multiple times and are no less problematic.   I am on `macos`